# Replacing a numeric value in a string using R

Tags: r

I want to replace `DM*13:01:01:02` with `DM*13:01:01:01`. However my script also changes `DM*11:01:01:01, DM*03:01:01:01, DM*01:01:01:01` to `DM*13:01:01:01`. I do not want these to be changed

The script I use:

```
> papST$DM_c1 <-gsub("[DM*]\\d[13][:]\\d[01][:]\\d[01][:]\\d[02]", "*13:01:01:01", papST$DM_o1, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should try entering your regex into a helper tool like https://regex101.com/. Your regex contains a lot of things that don't make sense to me, especially if you are basically trying to match a single fixed string.

Comment: `\\d` means any digit. `[xy]` matches any character `x` or `y`. So `\\d[13]` matches 01,03,11,13,21,23.... and so on. Why not just `gsub("DM*13:01:01:02", "DM*13:01:01:01", papST$DM_o1, fixed=TRUE)` ?

Comment: Thank you, my problem was I tried to over complicate a relatively simple substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples you have given, you don't really need to use any fancy regex features to do the specific replacement you have mentioned. The only thing you need to include in your pattern is a backslash so that `*` doesn't get treated as a special character:

```
x = c("DM*13:01:01:02", "DM*11:01:01:01", "DM*03:01:01:01", "DM*01:01:01:01")
gsub("DM\\*13:01:01:02", "DM*13:01:01:01", x)
```

If there are more values that need replacing, like you want to replace all values ending in `02`, then you may need to bring in some of the "pattern matching" features in regular expressions, but it's important not to overcomplicate things.

For reference, to replace all `02`s at the end of your strings, you could use a simple regex that uses `$`, which matches at the end of a string:

```
gsub("02$", "01", x)
```

Comment: Great a simple script works, I will remember this for the future.  Thank you!